# Getting the average on random grades

Tags: python, random, average

Does anyone know how to get the average of the random grades? She wants to generate just random grades and get the average but I had also done one where you input the grades on your end but I don't think that's what she was looking for.

```
import random

grade = random.randint(50,100)
grade2 = random.randint(50,100)
grade3 = random.randint(50,100)
grade4 = random.randint(50,100)
grade5 = random.randint(50,100)

if int(grade) >= 90 and int(grade) <= 100:
  print ("Grade 1:", grade, "A")
elif int(grade) >= 80 and int(grade) <=90:
  print("Grade 1:", grade, "B")
elif int(grade) >= 70 and int(grade) <= 80:
  print("Grade 1:", grade, "C")
elif int(grade) > 60 and int(grade) <=70:
  print("Grade 1:", grade,"D")
elif int(grade) <= 60:
  print("Grade 1:", grade, "F")
if int(grade2) >= 90 and int(grade2) <= 100:
  print ("Grade 2:", grade2, "A")
elif int(grade2) >= 80 and int(grade2) <=90:
  print("Grade 2:", grade2, "B")
elif int(grade2) >= 70 and int(grade2) <= 80:
  print("Grade 2:", grade2, "C")
elif int(grade2) > 60 and int(grade2) <=70:
  print("Grade 2:", grade2,"D")
elif int(grade2) <= 60:
  print("Grade 2:", grade2, "F")
if int(grade3) >= 90 and int(grade3) <= 100:
  print ("Grade 3:", grade3, "A")
elif int(grade3) >= 80 and int(grade3) <=90:
  print("Grade 3:", grade3, "B")
elif int(grade3) >= 70 and int(grade3) <= 80:
  print("Grade 3:", grade3, "C")
elif int(grade3) > 60 and int(grade3) <=70:
  print("Grade 3:", grade3,"D")
elif int(grade3) <= 60:
  print("Grade 3:", grade3, "F")
if int(grade4) >= 90 and int(grade4) <= 100:
  print ("Grade 4:", grade4, "A")
elif int(grade4) >= 80 and int(grade4) <=90:
  print("Grade 4:", grade4, "B")
elif int(grade4) >= 70 and int(grade4) <= 80:
  print("Grade 4:", grade, "C")
elif int(grade4) > 60 and int(grade4) <=70:
  print("Grade 4:", grade4,"D")
elif int(grade4) <= 60:
  print("Grade 4:", grade4, "F")
if int(grade5) >= 90 and int(grade5) <= 100:
  print ("Grade 5:", grade5, "A")
elif int(grade5) >= 80 and int(grade5) <=90:
  print("Grade 5:", grade5, "B")
elif int(grade5) >= 70 and int(grade5) <= 80:
  print("Grade 5:", grade5, "C")
elif int(grade5) > 60 and int(grade5) <=70:
  print("Grade 5:", grade5,"D")
elif int(grade5) <= 60:
  print("Grade 5:", grade5, "F")
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kraigolas pointed out, you can eliminate a lot of copied+pasted code by putting the grades into a list instead of 5 individual variables, and using `enumerate` to generate the "grade 1", "grade 2", etc.

The easiest way to get an average is to use `statistics.mean`, which gives you the mean (average) value of any list that you pass to it:

```
>>> grades = [70, 80, 85]
>>> import statistics
>>> statistics.mean(grades)
78.33333333333333
```

I'd also suggest putting the logic to determine a letter grade into a function, like this:

```
def letter_grade(grade: float) -> str:
    assert 0 <= grade <= 100
    for score, letter in [
        (90, "A"),
        (80, "B"),
        (70, "C"),
        (60, "D"),
    ]:
        if grade >= score:
            return letter
    return "F"
```

Now you can put it all together with a very small amount of code:

```
import random
import statistics

grades = [random.randint(50, 100) for _ in range(5)]

for n, grade in enumerate(grades, 1):
    print(f"Grade {n}: {letter_grade(grade)}")

print(f"Average: {letter_grade(statistics.mean(grades))}")
```

Sample output:

```
Grade 1: F
Grade 2: A
Grade 3: A
Grade 4: A
Grade 5: A
Average: B
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself putting a number after variable names, that's a big sign that you might want to use a list (or, in general, an iterable) to store the elements:

```
grades = [51, 62, 87, 57]
```

There are several ways to generate a list of random grades [`numpy.random.rand`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) is one, but an easier way for a beginner might be to just start off with a list like

```
grades = []
```

and then create a loop to append the grades. Python provides a `sum` function to sum up all of the values in your list, and a `len` function to compute the number of elements in the list. With these functions, you can compute the grades.

You can also use a list comprehension to generate the grades if you're familiar with them.

If you go ahead and create the grades list, your code can be adapted as follows:

```
for idx, grade in enumerate(grades, 1):
    label = f"Grade {idx}"
    if int(grade) >= 90 and int(grade) <= 100:
        print (label, grade, "A")
    elif int(grade) >= 80 and int(grade) <=90:
        print(label, grade, "B")
    elif int(grade) >= 70 and int(grade) <= 80:
        print(label, grade, "C")
    elif int(grade) > 60 and int(grade) <=70:
        print(label, grade,"D")
    elif int(grade) <= 60:
        print(label, grade, "F")
```

Here `enumerate(grades, 1)` returns an index and an element from `grades`, starting at 1 because we specify the 1 here.